# How to customize the login function in Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I started working on a C# Web API MVC project which had already been started using the Identity framework.  I'm trying to customize our login function to call an API and use a different hashing algorithm.  The issue into which I'm running is that I cannot find the login function.  Our frontend uses the route "api/token" to call it, but I can't find the route within my solution.  I'm sure this is something simple, but I am very new to Identity and don't know where to look.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the exact same problem...